# How to track the Internet connectivity of two PCs simultaneously using a script?

Tags: 14.04, python, scripts, cron, connection

I have two PCs and I want to monitor the Internet connectivity in both of them and make it available in a page (not local, and something like `example.com/statuses`) as to whether they're currently online and running. How can I do that?

I'm thinking of a cron job that gets executed every minute that sends a POST to a file located in a server, which in turn would write the connectivity status "online" to a file. In the page where the statuses are displayed, read from both the status files and display whether they're online or not. But this feels like a sloppy idea. What alternative suggestion do you have?How to track the Internet connectivity of two PCs simultaneously using a script?